# Does Dalvik (Androids JVM) support hot code replace?

Tags: android, dalvik

I tried with as simple replacing as changing value of String, but it does not work. I tried running my test app in debug mode, but always get "Hot Code Replace Failed" warning message box. Some sources says that it works, but it is very limited and occasionaly ignore all changes, other says it doesn't work at all.

**UPDATE:**
This behavior is exactly the same (does not work) on device and emulator.

Comment: Having developer android for 2+ years, I have never gotten it to work. I've set my Eclipse to stop displaying that useless warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Dalvik does not support any sort of hot code replacement, regardless of whether it's on device or emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Dalvik itself doesn't support this, but needed functionality can be achieved with additional tools. Won't post the name here because of minuses for advertisement:)

Comment: You can try and use this [Andorid hotswap code tool](http://www.instareloader.com/download) for free